# View log files real time in Tera term and pause terminal output for a while

Tags: linux, terminal, teraterm

In [Tera Term (Terminal emulator)](http://ttssh2.osdn.jp/), I was viewing log files real-time.
I used the command "tail -f ".
My question is ...

When I saw a log line I want to read, I would like to pause the terminal output for a while without stopping the "tail" process.

I heard there's a way to do that in tera term. But I cannot find out how to do.

Can anyone tell me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually your terminal is configured to honor XON/XOFF, as <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd> and <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>, e.g.,

```
$ stty -a
speed 38400 baud; rows 40; columns 80; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^H; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R;
werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff
-iuclc -ixany -imaxbel -iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt
echoctl echoke
```

While originally a *hardware* feature, this is more often emulated in *software*. By pressing <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>, you tell the computer to stop sending characters to the terminal, and pressing <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd> to resume.

For discussion, see

- [Xon/Xoff (X-on/X-off or XON/XOFF)](http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/Xon-Xoff-X-on-X-off-or-XON-XOFF)
- [What is flow control? What is RTS/CTS? What is Xon/Xoff?](http://www.modemhelp.net/faqs/flow.shtml)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the links, @Thomas_Dickey. It really explained well.